# Spring @ExceptionHandler handling multiple kinds of exceptions

Tags: spring, exception

I can't figure out how to handle more than one kind of exception by @ExceptionHandler.

I need to programmatically deal with these exceptions, for this I'd need a shared reference. Is this done via this reference "Exception ex" ? I don't think so, cause the exception is not caught like this, how would I do it then ?

I can't put all the exception references as arguments to the handler method, it wouldn't make sense, it can't be programmatically dealt with. I need a shared reference so that I could use "instanceof" on it or just send it somewhere else as a general "Exception"

```
@ExceptionHandler({DescriptionCstOrderException.class, SpecializationCstOrderException.class, NoUploadFileException.class,
                    DeadLineCstOrderException.class, DocumentCstOrderException.class, CommentCstOrderException.class})
public String handleFormException(Exception ex, ActionRequest actionRequest) {
    logger.error(ex.getMessage());
    SessionErrors.add(actionRequest, ex.getClass().getName());  
    return "mainOrderForm";
  }
```

Additional question: what if I wanted to handle `org.springframework.web.multipart.MaxUploadSizeExceededException`, that is not thrown from any method of the handler? Because `@ExceptionHandler` catches only exceptions that are thrown from one of the handler methods.

The `exceptionHandler` method could be placed into some extended parent controller but if one uses only `defaultAnnotationHandlerMapping`... ?

Appreciate any help, I'm going crazy, this is very frustrating....

Comment: Was the code edited? The answers suggest the same annotation form as the one in question.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

The @ExceptionHandler value can be set to an array of Exception types. If an exception is thrown matches one of the types in the list, then the method annotated with the matching @ExceptionHandler will be invoked. If the annotation value is not set then the exception types listed as method arguments are used. See the [documentation](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-exceptionhandlers) for details.

Answer (score 59):

The `@ExceptionHandler` value can be set to an array of Exception types.

The implementation of using exception array as mentioned in Spring [documentation](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-exceptionhandlers) will be like:

```java
@ExceptionHandler({
    NotFoundException.class,
    MissingServletRequestParameterException.class
 })
```

Answer (score -5):

Your question is rather confusing but your exception handler method will only handle one exception at a time.  It will not catch multiple exceptions and then pass both of them into your handleFormException() method.  If you need to handle these exception types differently then you should create an exception handler method for each one, specify an argument of that specific Exception type to your method, and then do the appropriate handling.  For example:

```
@ExceptionHandler(DescriptionCstOrderException.class)
public String handleDescriptionCstOrderException(DescriptionCstOrderException exception, ActionRequest actionRequest) {...}


@ExceptionHandler(SpecializationCstOrderException.class)
public String handleSpecializationCstOrderException(SpecializationCstOrderException exception, ActionRequest actionRequest) {...}

// and so on...
```

Please refer to the Spring documentation for further information:

http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-ann-exceptionhandler

Comment: I do want to handle them the same way. I put them into sessionErrors and viewlayer and javascript handles them differently then. What I wanted to know was, whether the sample of mine is correct, because the handleFormException method does not catch the exception of one of the types mentioned in the annotation value list...

Comment: if i declare one method for one exception type, it works...it's weird... Btw, do you know how to handle exceptions that are thrown outside the handler ? I mean using this @ExceptionHandlers... As I asked the additional question...