# Why Spring change the type of exception

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, exception

I have a filter for JWT which can throw a JWTDecodeException

```
public class JwtAuthenticationTokenFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {
    final JwtService jwtService;

    public JwtAuthenticationTokenFilter(JwtService jwtService) {
        this.jwtService = jwtService;
    }

    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain) throws ServletException, IOException {
        String token = jwtService.extractToken(request);
        if (StringUtils.hasLength(token)) {
            DecodedJWT decodedJWT = jwtService.validateToken(token);
            JwtAuthenticationToken authentication = new JwtAuthenticationToken(decodedJWT);
            authentication.setAuthenticated(true);
            SecurityContextUtils.setAuthentication(authentication);
        }
        filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
    }
}
```

Also I have a single error handler which handles all exceptions

```
@RequestMapping("/error")
@ExceptionHandler(Exception.class)
public ResponseEntity<Object> test(Exception ex, WebRequest request) {
    if (ex instanceof AccessDeniedException || ex instanceof JWTDecodeException) {
        System.out.println(123);
    }
    return handleExceptionInternal(ex, "test", new HttpHeaders(), HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR, request);
}
```

But I can't catch JWTDecodeException because for some reason the 'ex' param store simple Exception. I trace it with debug and saw when my JWTDecodeException becomes Exception, but I can't understand how to avoid it.
Moreover I can use `JWTDecodeExceptiont = (JWTDecodeException)request.getAttribute("javax.servlet.error.exception",0);` in handler and it will return JWTDecodeException.

Is there a way to get JWTDecodeException not from 'request' but from 'ex'?

Comment: Shouldn't you use `@ExceptionHandler({AccessDeniedException .class, JWTDecodeException.class})`? See, also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4221064/spring-exceptionhandler-handling-multiple-kinds-of-exceptions) SO question.

Comment: @JacobvanLingen it won't work because `@ExceptionHandler` and `@ControllerAdvice` can catch only controller exceptions.
Only reason why i can catch this exception here is `@RequestMapping("/error")`

Comment: I would set a breakpoint in your exception handler and check e.getCause() -> that might be your JWTDecodeException

Comment: @AlexanderKatsenelenbogen it's Null